# a: hover color not functioning properly on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I wanted to make a link with CSS hover. I am using font-face to make another font with JennaSue.

CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:JennaSue1;
    src: url(font/JennaSue.otf);  
} 
 @font-face {
    font-family:JennaSue3;
    src: url(font/JennaSue.ttf);  
} 
@font-face {
    font-family:JennaSue2;
    src: url(font/JennaSue.eot);  
} 

#australia {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:40px; 
    left:0px; 
    top:32px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-family: JennaSue1,JennaSue2,JennaSue3;
}
#australia a {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#fff;}
#australia a:hover { color:#b30101; }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="australia"><a href="#">Australia</a></div>
```

The font work well on chrome but when i hover link it show like [this picture](https://s18.postimg.cc/igsdzqytj/before.png):

[image: Hover image]

Thanks for the answer here link for you can see http://jsfiddle.net/6UdYd/1/;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as [Grezzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813332/885443) pointed out, there seems to be  something strange going on with the font. If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMCrf/1/), the left link is just like your example. I added a border to visualize the boundaries of the `a` element. There the "j" and the "p" protrudes outside this border. By adding a bottom and left padding to it (as done on the right link), the hover works as expected.

This is somewhat of a quick fix I guess, but I don't really know how to do it properly.

Comment: I used different background colours to visualize the boundaries, but you do appear to have found a nice solution, and that is to add a little bit of left padding to the a tag (the bottom padding wasn't necessary for it to work in my chrome.)

Comment: This ones the best answer for sure.. :)

Comment: @Grezzo Weird, for me the bottom padding was required for it to work (Chrome 20.0.1132.17 beta).

Comment: Are you saying that this http://jsfiddle.net/vMCrf/2/ doesn't work for you? Does the box cut throught the bottom of the j or something? I'm on Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m running on XP, and the box goes all the way round the word.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work. It cuts the j and the p with a few pixels (like 4 or 5). I'm running OSX 10.7.4 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be something to do with the left part of that j being to the left of where the actual character area starts. See this example (probably have to use chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/JGgHf/ where the left of the j has not been included in the div.

Comment: Perhaps jennasue has done something stange with the j to help with or work around kerning issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `font-weight`. This seems to solve the [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/6UdYd/2/).

```
#australia a:hover{
    color:#b30101;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Another possibility is to add a little bit of padding to the left so the text [fits](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/6UdYd/5/) in the a-tag.

```
#australia a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but without an explanation why, it seems a like a dirty hack

Comment: What's the problem with hacks when they work cross-browser and don't cause any problems?

Comment: It's not really much of a problem, I didn't down-vote or anything. It's just if you don't understand why they work (could be the result of a quirk that gets fixed later), then you can't be sure that they will keep working in the future.

Comment: It's probably to do with kerning and the built of the font. I've added another possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_katti/n37hC/2/

There is no error with the code that you have posted. The error might be with other elements related to it. Or the fonts you are using it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i modification your js fiddle but still doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/6UdYd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#australia a:link {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#fff;
}
#australia a:hover { color:#b30101; }
```

I've found that Chrome sometimes ignores my a styles unless I use the :link pseudo code.